# Retrieve document.title from AUT from acceptance test - Ember 2

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

I am testing an ember 2.13 app. I want to retrieve the value of the page title, but doing so as `document.title` from the test grabs the title from test suite page.
I may be overlooking a simple ember-qunit feature here. Any hint?

Comment: the qunit uses its own index.html page, and the title in it would be retrieved when you use `document.title`. Until and unless you are modifying the title dynamically inside the feature you are testing, the `title` of index.html related to qunit would only be called.

Comment: That's what I've noticed Sumit 33, hence why I am looking a way to retrieve in a test the document title for the AUT.

Answer (score 0):

Might be overkill, but you could use http://tim-evans.github.io/ember-page-title/. And test it like they do:

```
// Testem appends progress to the title...
// and there's no way to stop this at the moment
function title() {
  return findWithAssert('title', 'head').text().trim().replace(/^\(\d+\/\d+\)/, '');
}

test('the default configuration works', async function (assert) {
  assert.expect(1);
  await visit('/posts');

  assert.equal(title(), 'My App | Posts');
});
```

https://github.com/tim-evans/ember-page-title/blob/master/tests/acceptance/posts-test.js#L17-L28